# Ler dados do download usando o BackgroundWorker ProgressChanged

Tags: c#, .net

td bem? Eu sou muito novo em programação, peguei um projeto de um launcher com autoupdate já pronto e só editei algumas coisas. Ele basicamente faz download dos updates de um jogo.

Eu já mexi com outros projetos antes que usavam somente o WebClient para fazer download, porém esse launcher usa o BackgroundWorker, e até ai não nem problema. Só que esse BackgroundWorker usa o System.ComponentModel.ProgressChangedEventHandler e nele não tem as opções de bytesReceived e totalBytesToReceive como tem no WebClient. Então não consigo pegar os dados do download para mostrar quanto foi baixado e quanto falta.

Código usando o WebClient.DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs:

```
private void client_DownloadProgressChanged(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
        downloadLbl.Text = "Downloading Updates";
        label1.Text = e.ProgressPercentage + "%";
        double bytesIn = double.Parse(e.BytesReceived.ToString());
        double totalBytes = double.Parse(e.TotalBytesToReceive.ToString());
        double percentage = bytesIn / totalBytes * 100;
        label2.Text = "Downloaded " + e.BytesReceived + " of " + e.TotalBytesToReceive;

    }
```

Se eu coloco esse codigo acima não aparece nenhum erro, porém quando executa o programa e faz o download, a progressbar e os label não funcionam pois está usando BackgroundWorker para download do arquivo.

Código usando o BackgroundWorkder ComponentModel.ProgressChangedEventArgs:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {

        progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
        downloadLbl.Text = "Downloading Updates";
        label1.Text = e.ProgressPercentage + "%";
        double bytesIn = double.Parse(e.BytesReceived.ToString());
        double totalBytes = double.Parse(e.TotalBytesToReceive.ToString());
        double percentage = bytesIn / totalBytes * 100;
        label2.Text = "Downloaded " + e.BytesReceived + " of " + e.TotalBytesToReceive;

    }
```

Usando esse código a progressbar funciona e o progresso em % do label1 também, mas o label2 com os dados do download e quanto falta pra acabar não funcionam e o TotalBytesToReceive e BytesReceived ficam sublinhados em vermelho com um erro dizendo que "ProgressChangedEventArgs" não contém uma definição para TotalBytesToReceive/BytesReceived.

Alguém sabe alguma solução ou gambiarra que eu possa fazer pra resolver esse problema? Obrigado!!

Comment: Por que não usa um WebClient.DownloadAsync()?

Answer (score 0):

Bom dia,
ProgressChangedEventArgs efetivamente não contém essas propridades, como pode ver aqui:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.progresschanged(v=vs.110).aspx

Experimente algo parecido com este codigo alterando o necessário:

```
public partial class Update : Form
{
    public Update()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Update_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        string desktop = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory);
        client.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(client_DownloadProgressChanged);
        client.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(client_DownloadFileCompleted);
   client.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri("http://download.yourfile.zip"), desktop + "teste.zip");
    }

    void client_DownloadProgressChanged(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        progressBar1.Maximum = (int)e.TotalBytesToReceive / 100;
        progressBar1.Value = (int)e.BytesReceived / 100;
    }

    void client_DownloadFileCompleted(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        label2.Text = "Download Completed";
    }
}
```